# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter (получение id записи из БД)

Tags: cursor, getview, android, java

Не могли бы помочь, мне нужно при нажатии на кнопки и чекбоксы отображать ID записи из БД, а не номер позиции в списке.

**Вот мой адаптер:**

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
 Context ctx;

public Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    ctx = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    long id=getItemId(position);
    view.setTag(id);

    CheckBox cbBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
    cbBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myClickButtonCheck );
    cbBox.setTag(position);
    cbBox.setChecked(false);

    ImageView imgViewInfo=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImgInfo);
    imgViewInfo.setOnClickListener(myClickButtonInfo);
    imgViewInfo.setTag(position);

    ImageView imgViewRating=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImgRating);
    imgViewRating.setOnClickListener(myClickButtonRating);
    imgViewRating.setTag(position);

return view;
}

// обработчик для чекбоксов
OnCheckedChangeListener myClickButtonCheck = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
      boolean isChecked) {

  Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID"+buttonView.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
};

// обработчик для кнопок
OnClickListener myClickButtonInfo = new OnClickListener () {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

};

// обработчик для кнопок
OnClickListener myClickButtonRating = new OnClickListener () {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

};
```

}

**Вот рабочий пример:**

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
Context ctx;
Cursor cursor;//Добавил это
 public Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {

super(context, layout, c, from, to);
ctx = context;
cursor=c;//Добавил это
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
long id=getItemId(position);
view.setTag(id);
final int rowID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));  //Добавил это

CheckBox cbBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
cbBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myClickButtonCheck );
cbBox.setTag(rowID);
cbBox.setChecked(false);

ImageView imgViewInfo=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImgInfo);
imgViewInfo.setOnClickListener(myClickButtonInfo);
imgViewInfo.setTag(rowID);

ImageView imgViewRating=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImgRating);
imgViewRating.setOnClickListener(myClickButtonRating);
imgViewRating.setTag(rowID);

 return view;
 }

// обработчик для чекбоксов
OnCheckedChangeListener myClickButtonCheck = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
  boolean isChecked) {

Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID"+buttonView.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
};

 // обработчик для кнопок
OnClickListener myClickButtonInfo = new OnClickListener () {
 public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }

 };

   // обработчик для кнопок
   OnClickListener myClickButtonRating = new OnClickListener () {
   public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }

 };
 }
```

Comment: Твой запрос к БД записывает id строки в "Cursor c"? Если нет, то тебе надо добавить несколько слов в запрос что бы он и id возвращал. 
Ещё одно... id строки в БД, ты сможешь узнать только из Cursor, но не как не из "View v".

Answer (score 1):

1. добавь ViewHolder
2. тег ты ставишь, как бы правильно, и его отображаешь - в этом ошибка, ты должен не тег показывать, а объект на который он указывает
3. ты не биндишь курсор на вьюху

Comment: Все спасибо разобрался)